# Out front attatchment for mobile phones/GPS

Tags: gps, android

I'm looking for a case to mount my android as a GPS device.  I find that a lot of cases require attaching off centre (thus taking unecessary handlebar space), or have very bulky clips that don't fit around the stem, (and anyway, I like to have my cyclecomputer on the stem) or on the top bar, which often obstruct my legs or gets knocked.

Has anyone seen a mobile phone case which attaches like the Garmin out front system? (http://www.amazon.co.uk/Garmin-Out-front-Bike-Mount-Edge/dp/B0096855IO) which looks like it'd do a good job of keeping the GPS at the right position for reading, without obstructing the operation of the bike.

Edit: Nexus 4, weather proofing needed! (thanks)

Thanks

Comment: You need to say which phone and if you need weather proofing etc.

Comment: A friend of mine uses [this product](http://www.amazon.com/Bikemate-BlackBerry-Inspire-Sensation-Incredible/dp/B006N0T674/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1378740676&sr=8-6), the "Satechi Bikemate Slim Case 3". There seem to be a variety of similar devices on Amazon, which may be useful.

Comment: there are also attachments that act as a second handle bar "out front" for you to attach various devices to them. A sort of extension

Comment: Something like the [Topeak BarXtender](http://www.topeak.com/products/xtras/barxtender) might allow you to attach whatever mechanism you're using for your phone in centred in front of your handlebars.

Comment: what does your cycle computer offer that your phone doesn't? I got rid of mine when I bought a cheap handlebar mount for the phone (which is waterproof so the mount wouldn't suit you, and it was easily broken by other handlebars in a bike shed).

Comment: I like to have a cyclecomputer for the following reasons: Battery life, they're not so clunky or big, they're not so complex (one button on mine to cycle between speed, average speed, distance, time).  You can see them in direct sunlight, and they are not so valuable that I feel the need to remove them every time I leave the bike locked up.  Mine is also waterproof.  I use a phone for the GPS maps, which is why I'd want it mounted, but I usually just have it zipped in my back pocket for strava.

Answer (score 3):

DriKase and Drikase XL (for large phones or phones with cases) are good waterproof phone cases which mount to your stem and keep your phone dry while being able to operate it through the liner. It doesn't set it out front of your bars though.

[image: DriKase]

http://shop.alt-gear.com/c/bikase